# Connection refused when CiviCRM attempts to send test email via SMTP, using CiviHosting

Tags: civimail, extension

My ultimate aim is to connect CiviCRM to AWS SES using [Airmail](https://civicrm.org/extensions/airmail). As a preliminary step, I've set up the SMTP credentials in AWS SES and confirmed they are working correctly using this [SMTP Test Tool](https://www.gmass.co/smtp-test). Below is the output from the tool, and I do indeed receive the test email in my inbox.

[image]
[image]

However, when I enter the same credentials in CiviCRM a "connected refused" error occurs.

[image]

The contents of the log file is also shown below.

[image]

**How can I overcome this error within CiviCRM?** In case it's relevant, I'm running on a Shared Host provided by CiviHosting. My CiviCRM version is 5.55.2 and my WordPress version is 6.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this blog post: https://civihosting.com/blog/outgoing-smtp-on-civihosting/

It says you need to explicitly tell them if you want to connect to an external smtp server.

Comment: Thank you so much. That did the trick!